# IP to domain name worldwide

Tags: apache-http-server, web

I have everything set up to work like normal website but I can only access my website by typing in my router's IP address. I want to go on it by some kind of link. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You have to purchase the domain name from a site ([GoDaddy](https://www.godaddy.com/), [Wix](https://www.wix.com/), [Namecheap](https://www.namecheap.com/), etc.) that can register it in DNS, then you'll have to configure everything (adding records, setting up your backend, etc.) the way you need. On a side note: you don't necessarily have to create your website through any of those companies - many offer domain hosting services separately from site creation tools.

Comment: +1 for Namecheap. They actually have a Dynamic DNS client for purchased domains if you are running something from home (and you can technically use their DNS and dynamic client for free if your domain is registered elsewhere). GoDaddy doesn't do this (and I believe Wix doesn't either).

Comment: -1 The problem with answering a question like this is this will not ever be “the” answer. The original poster is saying “…go on it by some kind of link.” Which might mean a domain name? Or…? The question is vague because they state “I can only access my website by typing in my router's IP address.” This all reads to me like someone who has gotten in over their head. They can get to that IP via some kind of hairpinning on their internal network if they are asking a question like this and aren’t clear about the rest. Buying a domain name won’t solve the port mapping which is another issue.

Comment: @JakeGould while it’s certainly clear they are in over their head and it’s not a great question, the intent seems clear enough given the title and the wording of the question that my answer is appropriate; you’re both looking way too into it and making it sound like you didn’t read anything.

Comment: @mael' I read your answer and it basically boils down to your answer should be a comment on a bad question that can’t be fixed. A bad question is one like this that is a rabbit hole of an “[XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)” that you are encouraging.

Comment: @jakegould certainly a poorly worded question which i always initially assume is because of a language barrier, so if it gets taken down that’s fine - but the point remains that they are clearly asking how they can make their site available to the world via a domain name, and the answer to that is the one I provided. For all we know they have the technical skill to accomplish this but are not operating in their native language. If i had suggested something to try it should have been a comment - but this is what needs to happen, so it’s an answer.